# Is there any way to set workflow notification without setting up a new task list?

Tags: workflow

Today I got a request of setting Email notification within a SharePoint list that when a new item is added, send an Email to the person in "owner"conlumn. I try to use workflow but since the list I need to set email notificaiton is not a tast list and when I create a list workflow, there is always a task list created too. My customer has been using the list for a while and there are many items and views setting up. Is there any way to send email without create a task list?

Celia

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to use workflow without a task list. The workflow needs an associated task list because it doesn't know what you are going to do. In your case, simply let it create the task list (which it isn't going to use) then create an on creation workflow that emails the owner person.

The task list will only be used if you do something in the workflow that requires some sort of human interaction, like collecting feedback, approvals, or some other task based process.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric, your answer perfectly solve my questions.